# appending attribute to EOL with ansible according to prefix

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to append to the EOL of a log4j.propertis file a string, by using ansible. The problem is that the file has new lines and when trying to use the "backrefs" of the ansible's lineinfile module it adds the string under the line instead of appending to EOL.

The file is log4j properties file which have a line I want to edit. The line start with 'log4j.rootLogger' and I want to append to the EOL a string 'bla'

**This is how the line looks like now:** log4j.rootLogger=WARN, memory, servlet

**Expected after the change:** log4j.rootLogger=WARN, memory, servlet, bla

The ansible code I used where rootLoggerAppender is the attribute:

```
lineinfile:
    path: "{{ tomcat_path }}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties"
    regexp: '^(log4j.rootLogger=\.*)'
    line: '\1, {{ rootLoggerAppender }}'
    backrefs: yes
```

### **update:**

**when I cat log4j.properties the output as follows:**

```
# servlet appender - logs in memory only, allowing remote read of logs
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, memory, servlet
```

When I have update the ansible code to match the exact line the output was as expected.

```
lineinfile:
    path: "{{ tomcat_path }}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties"
    regexp: '^(log4j\.rootLogger=DEBUG, memory, servlet)'
    line: '\1, {{ rootLoggerAppender }}'
    backrefs: yes
```

---

I have also noticed the file is a windows file, and when converting it to a linux it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Correct *regexp* is below. Escaped dot match a dot only. The first dot should be escaped, but not the second one. This should match any character.

```
regexp: '^(log4j\.rootLogger=.*)$'
```

But this solution is not idempotent. Running this task will add the *appender* repeatedly

```
$ cat log4j.properties
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, memory, servlet, bla, bla
```

The *regexp* below makes the task idempotent

```
regexp: '^(log4j\.rootLogger=.*?)(, {{ rootLoggerAppender }})?$'
```

- make the first group non-gready
- the second group match 0 or 1  delimited *appender*

---

Given the file

```
$ cat log4j.properties
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, memory, servlet
```

The idempotent playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    rootLoggerAppender: bla
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: log4j.properties
        regexp: '^(log4j\.rootLogger=.*?)(, {{ rootLoggerAppender }})?$'
        line: '\1, {{ rootLoggerAppender }}'
        backrefs: true
```

gives

```
$ cat log4j.properties
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, memory, servlet, bla
```

---

The non-idempotent version of the playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    rootLoggerAppender: bla
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: log4j.properties
        regexp: '^(log4j\.rootLogger=.*)$'
        line: '\1, {{ rootLoggerAppender }}'
        backrefs: true
```

gives the same result

```
$ cat log4j.properties
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, memory, servlet, bla
```

, but when running repeatedly it keeps adding the delimited *appender*

```
$ cat log4j.properties
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, memory, servlet, bla, bla
```

Comment: this is the resulted line after your first regex suggestion: , *blaLogger=WARN, memory, servlet*

Comment: I can see the correct results. I've double-checked the examples and updated the answer. If you have any problem update the question with [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have update the question. it still won't update the file properly. the result is still the attribute in the beginning of the line as I mentioned above `blaLogger=WARN, memory, servlet` , so I tried to match the entire line and to run the code, and it worked !